# Safe strategy? In a simplified model of poker

Tags: poker-strategy, probability

I was just wondering where if there's any such thing as a safe strategy.

In a simplified model of Poker, each player is dealt 5 cards.Each player bets on the belief that their hand is worth more than the other players. Determine if a player who won on a pair of eights was using a ‘safe’ strategy.

Has this got anything to do with the probability of drawing a 'One Pair'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my interpretation, I think you could change the word "safe" with unexploitable. If that's the case then you are talking about using **Game Theory** to find strategies that can't be beaten by your opponents. It's possible of course but very difficult. That said, even getting close to an approximate game theoretical strategy will make you very successful. That's where I'd study if I want answers to this question. The topic is too broad perhaps to answer this individual case here.

As for the one pair part of the question, I dont understand what you mean. I hope this helps. Studying GT is hard but worth it.

Comment: Undoubtedly, GT can help you explore deep aspects of the game. But, it is more of a defense strategy, to help getting LESS exploited by equal or better opponents, in simple words. In poker there is no magic theoretical solution that will make you unbeatable. 

If you want to analyse further on the subject, you can read this --> [A GT approach to 3-card poker game](http://www.swansonsite.com/W/instructional/game_theory.pdf)